# Вставная конструкция и причастный оборот

Tags: вставная-конструкция, причастный-оборот

Из-за трагических перипетий истории в странах, где особенно активно производили манускрипты, -– Франции, Италии, Фландрии, Голландии, Англии -- множество рукописей просто погибло.

Грамота советует поставить запятую после *манускрипты*.

И у Розенталя:

Я забрался в угол, в кожаное кресло, такое большое, что в нём можно было лежать, – дедушка всегда хвастался, называя его креслом князя Грузинского, – забрался и смотрел, как скучно веселятся большие (М.Г.)

запятая, которая закрывает придаточное, - перед тире,

но в предложении у Куприна:

Рыбачьи лодки, с трудом отличаемые глазом – они казались маленькими, – неподвижно дремали в морской глади, недалеко от берега. (А.Куприн. Гранатовый браслет)

На сайте http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200100309 есть такое объяснение:

Вставная конструкция они казались маленькими обозначена парным тире, запятая после слова маленькими закрывает причастный оборот. Нетривиально здесь то, что вставную конструкцию автор решил ввести в состав причастного оборота.

Вроде причастный оборот во втором примере и придаточное в первом "одного порядка" при расстановке запятых в предложениях с вставными конструкциями. Как тогда объяснить, постановку запятых?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из-за трагических перипетий истории в странах, где особенно активно производили манускрипты, -– Франции, Италии, Фландрии, Голландии, Англии -- множество рукописей просто погибло.-это не вставная конструкция,а  однородные члены к обобщающему слову В СТРАНАХ,которые носят характер пояснения и обособлены с помощью двух тире, а запятая закрыла придаточное предложение, которое отдалило однородные члены от обобщающего слова СТРАНЫ

В следующих предложениях действительно вставные конструкции, можно было бы поставить одинаковые знаки, можно было заменить тире скобками, но каждый автор ставит знаки препинания так, чтобы они помогли передать его мысль, его чувствования.

Горький вставную конструкцию относит целиком к пояснению ТАКОЕ БОЛЬШОЕ, ЧТО В НЁМ МОЖНО БЫЛО ЛЕЖАТЬ, поэтому запятая перед тире нужна, чтобы закрыть придаточное, а вторая нужна, чтобы отделить повторяющееся слово забрался.

Куприн  же относит вставную конструкцию к причастному обороту: они казались маленькими, поэтому и были с трудом отличаемы, а не к слову ЛОДКИ,так что всё объяснимо, запятая закрывает причастный оборот..Можно было и так:
Рыбачьи лодки – они казались маленькими,с трудом отличаемые глазом  – неподвижно дремали в морской глади, недалеко от берега.

Comment: 10. Если находящаяся в середине предложения группа однородных членов, стоящих после обобщающего слова, имеет характер уточняющего замечания или может быть приравнена к обособленным приложениям, то она с обеих сторон выделяется тире (см. п. 9): Все это — звуки и запах, тучи и люди — было странно красиво и грустно (М.Г.); В четырёх городах Италии — Риме, Неаполе, Турине и Милане — приняла старт финальная часть футбольного чемпионата Европы (газ.); Все присутствующие — делегаты и гости — внимательно слушали докладчика.

Comment: Однородные члены _Франции, Италии, Фландрии, Голландии, Англии_ - носят характер пояснения или уточнения?

Comment: Проблема в том, что это и уточнение, и пояснение одновременно. Пояснение (к слову страны), потому что страны = Франция, Италия и т.д.,уточнение к конструкции "в странах, где особенно активно производили манускрипты".Здесь однородные члены-приложения, а они и поясняют, и уточняют.http://www.filologdirect.ru/content/predlozheniya-s-obosoblennymi-chlenami?page=4 Собст. имя  может выступать в роли обос. приложения, если служит для пояснения или уточнения нарицательного существительного (перед ним  можно вставить "а именно". Напр. Остальные братья, Мартын и Прохор, до мелочей схожи с Алексеем.

Comment: http://portal-slovo.ru/philology/37431.php - здесь подробно о пояснении и уточнении, продолжение на 2 стр. этой же ссылки.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что здесь "они казались маленькими" выступает в роли пояснения к причастному обороту, поэтому ставится первое тире и нет запятой после "глазом".